# Can I access SoundCloud API without authenticating?

Tags: java, api, authentication, soundcloud

I am using [`java-api-wrapper`](https://github.com/soundcloud/java-api-wrapper) to use the SoundCloud API in Java, and I want to access resources without authenticating.

In the readme examples, the usage is:

```
ApiWrapper wrapper = new ApiWrapper("client_id", "client_secret", null, null);

// Do I HAVE to do this?
wrapper.login("username", "password");

HttpResponse resp = wrapper.get(Request.to("/me"));
HttpResponse resp =
    wrapper.put(Request.to("/me")
        .with("user[full_name]", "Che Flute",
            "user[website]",   "http://cheflute.com")
        .withFile("user[avatar_data]", new File("flute.jpg")));
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried it without that statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soundcloud relies on tokens that are produced from logging in to fulfill your requests. Your client will be useless without one.

Answer (score 0):

From the API doc on [github](https://github.com/soundcloud/java-api-wrapper/blob/master/src/main/java/com/soundcloud/api/ApiWrapper.java#L141) it looks like there is an exception thrown when there is no username or password. So I don't think you can use the API without authentication.